# Where is the flaw in my stable partition algorithm?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Trying to write it recursively in JavaScript. I'm getting the same array as before (i.e. nothing changes).

Where's the flaw?

```
function unstable_partition ( arr, f )
{
      if(arr.length <= 1)
        return arr;
    var n = arr.length - 1;
    if(f(arr[0]))
        return unstable_partition(arr.slice(0,n),f).concat([arr[0]]);
    else if(!f(arr[n]))
        return [arr[n]].concat(unstable_partition(arr.slice(0,n - 1),f));
    else 
        return [arr[0]].concat(unstable_partition(arr.slice(1,n - 1)),f).concat([arr[n]]); 
}

var isEven = function(x) { return x % 2 == 0; }
var myArray = [1,2,3,3,4,5];
alert(unstable_partition(myArray,isEven).join(","));
```

Comment: It doesn't return the same array for me. And btw, you misclosed your last return, shouldn't it be `return [arr[0]].concat(unstable_partition(arr.slice(1,n - 1),f)).concat([arr[n]]);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slice does not include last element, no need to do "-1" when you call it

Corrected code:
https://jsfiddle.net/n7g7yfju/

```
function unstable_partition ( arr, f )
{
      if(arr.length <= 1)
        return arr;
    var n = arr.length - 1;
    if(f(arr[0]))
        return unstable_partition(arr.slice(0,n),f).concat([arr[0]]);
    else if(!f(arr[n]))
        return [arr[n]].concat(unstable_partition(arr.slice(0,n),f));
    else 
        return [arr[0]].concat(unstable_partition(arr.slice(1,n),f)).concat([arr[n]]); 
}

var isEven = function(x) { return x % 2 == 0; }
var myArray = [1,2,3,3,4,5];
alert(unstable_partition(myArray,isEven).join(","));
```